# restriced key sort in unix

Tags: unix

I have a file file1.txt  with data:

```
2010/09/04,21:53:42.048,a
2010/09/04,21:53:40.923,b
2010/09/04,21:53:40.923,a
2010/09/04,21:50:42.048,a.
```

I want to sort the file based on time stamp. I am currently using

```
 sort  -t% -k1.1,1.23 file1.txt > file2.txt
```

My expected output is

```
2010/09/04,21:50:42.048,a
2010/09/04,21:53:40.923,b
2010/09/04,21:53:40.923,a
2010/09/04,21:53:42.048,a
```

But, I am getting the following output

```
2010/09/04,21:50:42.048,a
2010/09/04,21:53:40.923,a
2010/09/04,21:53:40.923,b
2010/09/04,21:53:42.048,a
```

I am using SFU3.5 for windows. My sort usage is

usage: sort [-o output] [-cmubdfinr] [-t char] [-T char] [-k keydef] ... [files]

Please provide possible soultion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't get a sort with a "stable" option then you can make an extra key with "cat -n", or awk, use that in the sort when you need the original order, and strip it off later.  Why not tell sort that comma is the field separator too, then you don't need to count 23 characters.

```
awk '{print NR "," $0}' dat | sort -t, -k2,2 -k1n,1 | sed 's/^[^,]*,//'
```

A [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort) is one that preserves the original order if the sort keys are equal.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a [stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) problem, so try to use the `--stable` option:

```
-s, --stable
      stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison
```

**Update:**
It seems that SFU does not support the `-s` option and is unstable all the time. You can try to use an alternative sort, like the one shipped with [unxutils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/).

Comment: I am using SFU3.5 for windows. sort usage is sort: illegal option '-'
usage: sort [-o output] [-cmubdfinr] [-t char] [-T char] [-k keydef] ... [files]

Comment: @padmakumar: the problem is that you get an unstable sort and you can't use the `-s` option with SFU. You should consider to use another implementation - see my update.

Comment: Thanks tanascius for the support.